# Replace or update an object in a list knowing only its UUID

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I know similar questions have been asked already, but every time the answers revolve around "use a Map instead".

In my case, I HAVE to use a List. More precisely, I can use other data structures for treatment, but the information will be stored ultimately in the form of a List.

Here is the situation : I have an object, which I will call `Sequence`, containing a `List` of objects I will call `Phase`.

Among other properties, the `Phase` object is given a UUID through `ObjectId`

During a given treatment, I have to replace an existing `Phase` *inside* the `List<Phase>` contained in `Sequence` by another `Phase`. The input for this are the replacement `Phase` object and a `String` value of the `ObjectId` of the `Phase` to replace

I was hoping to be able to do something like this using Java8 :

```
public void replacePhase(Sequence sequence, Phase replacementPhase, String idPhaseToBeReplaced) {
         List<Phase> phaseList = sequence.getPhaseslist();
         Phase phaseToBeReplaced = phaseList.stream().filter(p -> p.getId().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(idPhaseToBeReplaced)).findFirst().orElse(null);
         if (phaseToBeReplaced != null) {
             phaseToBeReplaced = replacementPhase;
         }
```

And voilà, the `List<Phase>` would be updated.

I know something like this will work :

```
    public void replacePhase(Sequence sequence, Phase replacementPhase, String idPhaseToBeReplaced) {
             List<Phase> phaseList = sequence.getPhaseslist();
             Phase phaseToBeReplaced = phaseList.stream().filter(p -> p.getId().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(idPhaseToBeReplaced)).findFirst().orElse(null);
             if (phaseToBeReplaced != null) {
                 int i = phaseList.indexOf(phaseToBeReplaced );
                 phaseList.set(i, replacementPhase);
                 phaseToBeReplaced = replacementPhase;
             }
```

But it doesn't seem more efficient that using a `for` loop  on `phaseList` with a `break` when finding a `Phase` with the desired UUID.

So my question is : is there a way, using List data structure, to find an object based on a (in this case, unique) property and then replace said object inside the List by another (of the same type), preserving order? Preferably without iterating over the whole List and using Java8 functionnalities?

Comment: "But it doesn't seem more efficient than using a for loop". Have you made the mistake of assuming Streams are *faster* than for loops? There's no reason to shoehorn streams in this, especially if the ids are unique and you can stop processing when you've found one.

Comment: Maybe I worded this sentence poorly : I meant to say that by using this approach, I might as well use a `for` loop which would just take more lines to write and make the use of `stream` completely useless. And that I am hoping for a trick involving something built in `stream` to do just that.
But if `stream` is not necessary to do that, I'm totally fine with it.

Comment: Well, `List.replaceAll()` would come closest, but that will process the whole list. A normal for loop (or a `ListIterator`) should give you small enough code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your replace functionality work in short-circuit fashion, use `ListIterator`:

```
ListIterator<Phase> iterator = phaseList.listIterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Phase phase = iterator.next();
    if(phase.getId().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(idPhaseToBeReplaced)){ 
        iterator.set(replacementPhase);
        break;
    }
}
```

In case the id is not unique, just remove the `break`. Or use `List::replaceAll`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for [`List#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) such as :

```
sequence.getPhasesList()
        .replaceAll(phase -> phase.getId().toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(idPhaseToBeReplaced) ? replacementPhase : phase);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the list sorted you can find the item using binary search, that would be faster than iterating the list.

```
    Collections.binarySearch
```

If you need to keep it sorted by insertion order, use a `LinkedHashMap`